# LocationServices.SettingsApi Reset SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE flag

Tags: android, google-play-services

Updating to Google Play Services v7.0+, and based in [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java) for LocationUpdates in Android, I have the following code to connect to the `LocationServices.SettingsApi` and check if user has everything OK for the Application receive the location updates.

```
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mLocationClient,
                    mLocationSettingsRequest
            );
    result.setResultCallback(this);
```

Where `this` is the following callback:

```
    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        Intent resolutionIntent;
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // Everything is OK, starting request location updates
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                // Seems the user need to change setting to enable locations updates, call startResolutionForResult(Activity, REQUEST_CODE)
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Error, cannot retrieve location updates.
                break;
        }
    }
```

The `SUCCESS` it OK to reproduce, just keep GPS enabled.

The `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` is also OK to reproduce, only disable GPS.

The `SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE` is the deal: If user select "NEVER" when the step `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` is executed, the result will come with this status always.

Did the Google Play Services has a option to reset **programmatically** the flag when user select the "NEVER" option?

I know that "NEVER" seems to be "***Really, don't ask me again!!!***", but I thinking to create a option in case the user change his mind, of course, if this can be possible.

In this case I'll be able to receive the status `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` again and ask to user to accept the LocationUpdates when the app is executed next time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[LocationSettingsRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest.Builder.html) has a method [setAlwaysShow](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest.Builder.html#setAlwaysShow(boolean)) that changes the buttons of the dialog:

> Always show the dialog, without the "Never" option to suppress future
>   dialogs from this app. When this flag is set to true, the dialog will
>   show up if the location settings do not satisfy the request, even if a
>   user has previously chosen "Never". NOTE: Only use this method if your
>   dialog is the result of an explicit user-initiated action that
>   requires location to proceed. Canceling this dialog should also cancel
>   the initiated action.

Instead the default *Yes*, *Not now* and *Never* buttons if you call `setAlwaysShow(true);` you will have only *Yes* and *No*, so the user won't choose *Never* and you will never receive `SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE`

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
builder.setAlwaysShow(true); 
mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                mLocationClient,
                mLocationSettingsRequest
        );

result.setResultCallback(this);
```

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Nice solution! I noticed Google Maps did not have a _Never_ button, but couldn't figure out how it did it, and was almost going to implement a custom dialog without the _Never_ button. Your solution saved the day!

Comment: just a note people - if you have airplane mode on, and location off while requesting this, you will actually receive a SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE, even if you have setAlwaysShow

Comment: @SaikCaskey Thanks for that. Solved my problem.

Comment: @SaikCaskey Is there any way to make it work with airplane mode?

Comment: @JacopoTosi nope, honestly our app just does nothing and hopes you didn't try it :|

Comment: @JacopoTosi assuming you receive the SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE because of airplane mode and not because of rejected permission, you can add an if condition when receiving the status code SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE. Check if the network is connected or not. If the network doesn't connected just fetch the latest location/latest cached location. For me I use `fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
            locationData = LocationData(it?.latitude.orZero(), it?.longitude.orZero())
        }`