# How can I prompt a user to give location permissions after they chose to "Never" allow it?

Tags: android, user-interface, google-api, location

**EDIT** [Margaret Bloom's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861580/locationservices-settingsapi-reset-settings-change-unavailable-flag) was exactly what I am looking for.

I'm writing an app that recommends food based on where you are at the time, so without location information my app is basically useless. Here's how I'm accessing the location data programatically.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    //adds the location request
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocReq);

    //make sure the phone is giving us what we asked for
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                    builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:  //we have what we want
                    Log.v("Location settings", "Location settings are satisfied.");
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    Log.v("Location Settings", "Location settings not satisfied. Starting REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS");
                    //we need to ask user before phone will give location information
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(LaunchActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // This phone can't give us what we need.
                    Log.e("Location Settings", "The user \"never\" wants to give us location info");
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(LaunchActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS: //if we got the request check settings callback
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.i("Location Settings", "onActivityForResult returned RESUME_OK");
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.i("Location Settings", "user did not want to give us location permissions");
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

If the user picks "Never" on the dialog box the **LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:** case is set and the phone no longer allows me to display the location request dialog. Restarting the app and manually enabling location data doesn't work either and my app is prevented from sending location updates.

So from the programming side and the UX side what are the best ways I can prompt my user again to give location permissions?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861580/locationservices-settingsapi-reset-settings-change-unavailable-flag)

Answer (score 0):

You can't prompt user if he/she has selected **never** to ask again. What you can do the best is that you can land your user to the app page in settings. Where he/she would have to allow permission manually.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                      Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Example:
[image: Example of the answer]

Image source: Google Images